# Notifying activity of fragment swiped into view via a pager

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am having trouble implementing a feature in my Android app.

Here's the setup:

- `ItemPagerActivity`: An activity that contains a fragment that displays a pager.
- `ItemPagerFragment`: The fragment containing a pager that loads other fragments. A cursor is used to load the fragments.
- `ItemFragment`: The fragment in the pager, which performs an asynchronous task to load its data.

What I want is the following:

- as a I swipe pages, the data in the currently displayed `ItemFragment` is communicated to the `ItemPagerActivity` (specifically, the name of the item will be used as the activity's title).

I've defined a listener in `ItemFragment` that notifies when the data is loaded:

```
public class ItemFragment ... {

    public interface OnItemLoadedListener {
        public void onItemLoaded(Item item);
    }

    private Collection<OnItemLoadListener> listeners;

    private class LoadItemTask extends AsyncTask<...> {
        ...
        public void onPostExecute(Item item) {
            notifyItemLoaded(item);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If this fragment was wrapped by an `Activity`, then I could set the activity's title simply by doing the following:

```
public class ItemActivity {

    public void onCreate(...) {
        ...
        ItemFragment fragment = new ItemFragment();
        fragment.registerItemLoadedListener(new ItemLoadedListener() {
            public void onItemLoaded(Item item) {
                setTitle("Item: " + item.getName());
            }
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

So that's easy enough, and works as expected: when the activity starts, it creates the fragment, which loads the item, which notifies the activity, and the title is updated correctly.

But with `ItemPagerFragment`, the fragments are loaded pre-emptively: swiping to Fragment 3 may mean that Fragment 4 and Fragment 5 are created. Receiving notifications from the `ItemFragment` class when items are loaded is not correct here because the fragment displayed may not match the fragment that performed the last load.

Now the `ViewPager` class has a `OnPageChangeListener` which could be a solution: when I swipe, this listener is invoked with the current page number. From that page number, I need to (somehow) get the fragment representing that page from the adapter, get the `Item` data out of the fragment, and notify listeners that the `Item` is now loaded:

```
public class ItemPagerFragment ... {

    private Collection<OnItemLoadedListener> listeners;

    public View onCreateView(...) {
        ...
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager):
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            public void onPageChange(int pageNumber) {
                ItemFragment fragment = getItemFragment(pageNumber);
                Item item = fragment.getLoadedItem();
                notifyItemLoaded(item);
            }
         });
         ...
    }

}
```

The `ItemPagerActivity` class would then register as a listener on the `ItemPagerFragment` class as follows:

```
class ItemPagerActivity ... {

    public void onCreate(...) {
        ...
        ItemPagerFragment fragment = new ItemPagerFragment();
        fragment.registerOnItemLoadedListener(new OnItemLoadedListener() {
            public void onItemLoaded(Item item) {
                setTitle("Item: " + item.getName());
            }
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

This looks good, but there are a number of problems:

- The `OnPageChangeListener` may be invoked before a fragment has loaded its data (i.e., the fragment is swiped into view before the item has asynchronously loaded). So the call to `fragment.getLoadedItem()` may return `null`.
- The `OnPageChangeListener` is not invoked for the initial page (only when a page changes, e.g. after a swipe action) so the activity title will be incorrect for the initial page.
- The `ViewPager` class allows for only one `OnPageChangeListener`. This is a problem because I am also using the `ViewPageIndicator` library, which wants to assign a listener to the `ViewPager`.

I'm assuming that this pattern (notifying the activity of the data in a fragment that has been swiped into view) might be common, so I am wondering if there are any good solutions for this pattern, and to the three specific problems that I have identified above.

Comment: Just go this link check for example,,

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854064/android-viewpager-touck-or-click/13854281#13854281][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854064/android-viewpager-touck-or-click/13854281#13854281

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I followed the links above but both seem to be generic examples of creating a ViewPager. Can you explain how either provide some insight into the issues I described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...so I am wondering if there are any good solutions for this pattern,
>   and to the three specific problems that I have identified above.

I don't know if I would call it a pattern but the `OnPageChangeListener` is the way to go.

> The OnPageChangeListener may be invoked before a fragment has loaded
>   its data (i.e., the fragment is swiped into view before the item has
>   asynchronously loaded). So the call to fragment.getLoadedItem() may
>   return null.

First, your code should handle the "no data available situation" from the start. Your `AsyncTasks` will have the job of loading the data and also update the title **only if** the fragment for which they are working is the visible one(a position field in the `ItemFragment` tested against the `ViewPager`'s `getCurrentItem()` method). The `OnPageChangeListener` will handle the update of the title **after** the data was loaded, as the user switches between pages and the data is available(it will return null if no data is available). To get the `ItemFragment` for a certain position you could use the code below:

```
    ItemFragment itf = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag(
                    "android:switcher:" + R.id.theIdOfTheViewPager + ":"
                            + position);
    if (itf != null) {
        Item item = fragment.getLoadedItem();
            notifyItemLoaded(item);
    }
```

> The OnPageChangeListener is not invoked for the initial page (only
>   when a page changes, e.g. after a swipe action) so the activity title
>   will be incorrect for the initial page.

See above.

> The ViewPager class allows for only one OnPageChangeListener. This is
>   a problem because I am also using the ViewPageIndicator library, which
>   wants to assign a listener to the ViewPager

I admit I don't have much knowledge on the `ViewPagerIndicator` library but at a quick look on its site I saw:

> (Optional) If you use an OnPageChangeListener with your view pager you
>   should set it in the indicator rather than on the pager directly.
>
> `titleIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);`

I don't see where is the limitation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I somehow overlooked the section in the `ViewPageIndicator` documentation regarding where to assign the `OnPageChangeListener`. I remember reading it before, but it had escaped me. So that's one problem solved.

Comment: I also modified the pager adapter in `ItemPagerFragment` to add a `onLoadItemListener` when the fragment is created. This listener will check if that fragment matches the currently visible fragment; if so, it will then notify the activity. This seems to take care of the "`onPageChangeListener` not invoked for initial page" problem.

Comment: However, I'm not sure of that the tag used to locate the fragment ("android:switcher" + ...") is the correct solution going forward. That tag is constructed within a private method in `FragmentPagerAdapter`and may change in a future API version.

Comment: Regarding `onPageChangeListener`: I think there's still a chance that a fragment will swipe into view before the data in that fragment is asynchronously loaded. I've added guards against `getLoadedItem()` returning null, and so far by observing the app's behaviour it seems that the data is loaded just in time, but there's still a nagging suspicion that this will not always be true (perhaps on slower devices). But I guess adding the `onLoadItemListener` I mentioned in the second comment will handle that case.

Comment: Despite the caveat on using a internal fragment tag, I'll make this as an answer.

Comment: @JohnQCitizen That private(awful indeed to rely on non public behavior) tag trick is the simplest two line code for retrieving fragments from the `ViewPager`. You are always welcome to roll your own `FragmentPagerAdapter` to better handle this( see the source code http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.java/). Regarding the solution above failing, i don't see it happen but if you manage to break it don't hesitate to mention it to me.

Comment: @JohnQCitizen If the fragments didn't load the data yet you'll handle this by the null safe guard. In the rest I can't see the code failing, at most the listener for setting the title will be called two times for the same fragment(for example, you switch to the fragment, `onPageChanghe` is called, also the listener will be called again if the task finishes loading the data while the fragment is still visible). You may also want to cache those titles in the fragments themselves if they don't change from one run of the app to another.

Answer (score 0):

For my purposes, it worked to use `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected()` in conjunction with `Fragment.onActivityCreated()` to perform an action when the Fragment is visible. `Fragment.getUserVisibleHint()` helps too.